# discord.py : sending message on a channel 2-3 times

Tags: python, async-await, discord, discord.py

I did a bot Discord using Discord.py pushing notifications on a channel when I receive a new mail from a specific sender on my Gmail account. It loops every 60 sec.
I did something like this :

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def get_message():
    channel = bot.get_channel(CHANNEL_NB)
    
    # Call the Gmail API and get all new message with Google query

    if not messages:
        print('You have no new messages.')
    else:
        message_count = 0
        for message in messages:
            msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
            message_count += 1
        print('You have ' + str(message_count) + " unread messages.")
        guild = bot.guilds[1]
        group = get(guild.roles, name='NotifierGmail')
        await channel.send(f'{group.mention} You have ' + str(message_count) + " unread message(s)")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    get_message.start()
    print('Bot is ready.')
    print('------')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

The bot is doing well but it sends sometimes 2 or 3 notifications and I don't understand why.
I host the bot on Heroku.

Comment: You're simply hitting ratelimits

Comment: One thing I can think of is that you might be running your code on your local machine as well. Since your code is already running on Heroku, this would cause your bot to print the messages more than once.

Comment: @AdityaTomar For testing, I run my code on my local machine, but only for testing. I don't know if it is enough to make the bot offline with a CTRL + C

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński is there a rate limit ? I don't see that on the documentation

Comment: Yeah if you do a CTRL + C, you're bot will go offline but only on your local machine. It will continue to run on Heroku.